# Moment and new Date() not displaying local time

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to display the local date of the user, but nothing is working for me. It always returns the UTC time.

I have tried:

1. This returns UTC - also in here offset comes as zero.

```
let visitDate = moment.utc().format();
let offset = moment().utcOffset();
let visitDate1 = moment.utc(visitDate).utcOffset(offset)
```

2. This returns UTC

```
let visitDate = new Date()
let visitDate1 = moment(visitDate).local().format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```

3. This returns UTC

```
let visitDate = new Date()
let visitDate1 = visitDate.toLocaleDateString()
```

I have tried several methods, but it doesn't matter what I do, I always get UTC time. If I try on localhost then it displays the correct time, but once I host the page it displays UTC.

How can I transform to local?

Comment: Where does this code run? (And by that I mean both "client or server" and "where on planet Earth")

Comment: Im in the US with CDT Time, and the wrong is coming from the server.

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` shows the date, so you're not so offset from UTC that it makes a difference...

Comment: `.toLocaleString()` works correctly for me (also Central); I get the actual local time in the result.

Comment: If I try it on localhost It works for me too, but once is posted into my database its coming as UTC. Example right now its 10:59 AM and if I send the information it displays 15:59. Is there a way I can change this?

Comment: Maybe your server is set up to have UTC as its local time; that's not uncommon.

Comment: Not just uncommon, but actually a best practice.  Servers should have their time zones set to UTC, ***and*** code running on a server should not depend on that time zone setting.

Answer (score 3):

`moment().local()` uses the timezone of the local machine, that's why it works in localhost

if you know it, I would specify the timezone:

```
moment.tz("America/Los_Angeles").format()
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several possible points of failure. I'll list the ones I think of below, and you can assess whether they're relevant to your setup.

**1) The code that manipulates the date is executed on the server, not locally**
Most of our Javascript code is written to execute in the user's browser, so that's the default assumption. If that assumption is wrong in this case, and the code is being executed on the server, then "local" means "on the server." Your server should be running with UTC time, which could produce the results you're seeing.

**2) The user is running a browser set to UTC**
If the browser you're using for testing is set to consider UTC as local time, it'd produce the results you're seeing. Since you're probably using the same machine for localhost and for testing, it's an unlikely source of the problem...but worth noting nonetheless.

**3) Changing how the date is displayed does not change how the date is stored**
Many of the tools we have for setting/changing the time zone affect how the date is displayed. However, Date objects in Javascript are stored using Unix Time (in milliseconds), which is UTC. When you create a Date object--even with a time zone specified--the behind-the-scenes representation will still be an integer (representing a number of milliseconds) and based on UTC. If you're checking the stored value rather than the displayed value, when you're testing, then there's a good chance you'll always see UTC. *However*, the work you're doing with the moment library should have the date formatted correctly. If you're checking the moment object, you should be seeing the time zone you expect to see.

If none of these three possible failure points applies to your context, then perhaps they spark an idea for you. (The third one, especially, feels like it might be on the right track even if it's not what's happening in your case.)

Comment: Wow this really helps me understand better! Thank you!!